# Coding with powershell

Tags: powershell, loops, timeout

I'm new with powershell and i would like to use a loop to ping several Printers on my network.

My problem is : once i'm in the loop of pinging , i can't go out of the loop ...

I tried several things from google but without success ( start-stop , Timer ) . Does anybody have any idea?

Here is the code :

```
$BtnStartPingClicked = {
    if ($LblFileSelectPing.Text -eq "*.txt") {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
        $ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::OK
        $MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Error
        $MessageBody = "Please select a list of printer first"
        $MessageTitle = "Error"
        $Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)
        Write-Host "Your choice is $Result"
    }
    else {
        do {
            $IPList = Get-Content ($LblFileSelectPing.Text)
            $snmp = New-Object -ComObject olePrn.OleSNMP
            $ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
            $i = 11
            $j = 1
                            
            foreach ($Printer in $IPList) {  
                try {
                    $result = $ping.Send($Printer)
                } catch {
                    $result = $null
                }
                                
                if ($result.Status -eq 'Success') { 
                    $((Get-Variable -name ("GBMachine"+$j+"Ping")).value).Visible = $True
                    $j++
                    test-Connection -ComputerName $Printer -Count 1 -Quiet 
                    $printerip = $result.Address.ToString()
                    # OPEN SNMP CONNECTION TO PRINTER
                    $snmp.open($Printer, 'public', 2, 3000)

                    # MODEL
                    try { 
                        $model = $snmp.Get('.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1') 
                    } catch { 
                        $model = $null 
                    }
                    # Serial
                    try { 
                        $serial = $snmp.Get('.1.3.6.1.4.1.1602.1.2.1.8.1.3.1.1').toupper() 
                    } catch { 
                        $Dns = $null 
                    }
                                    
                    # progress
                    $TBMonitoringPing.SelectionColor = "green"   
                    $TBMonitoringPing.AppendText("$Printer is Pinging") 
                    $TBMonitoringPing.AppendText("`n")
                                                                 
                    $mac = (arp -a $Printer | Select-String '([0-9a-f]{2}-){5}[0-9a-f]{2}').Matches.Value
                
                    # OPEN SNMP CONNECTION TO PRINTER
                    $((Get-Variable -name ('LblMach' + $i)).value).Text = "IP : $Printerip"  
                    $i++
                    $((Get-Variable -name ('LblMach' + $i)).value).Text = "Model : $Model"
                    $i++
                    $((Get-Variable -name ('LblMach' + $i)).value).Text = "MAC : $mac"
                    $i++
                    $((Get-Variable -name ('LblMach' + $i)).value).Text = "Serial : $serial"
                    $TBAnswerMachine.AppendText("$Model")
                    $TBAnswerMachine.AppendText("`n")
                    $TBAnswerMachine.AppendText("$Printer - $Serial")
                    $TBAnswerMachine.AppendText("`n")
                    $TBAnswerMachine.AppendText("$Mac")
                    $TBAnswerMachine.AppendText("`n")
                    $TBAnswerMachine.AppendText("`n")

                    Get-Content ($LblFileSelectPing.Text) | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch $Printer} | Set-Content ("C:\_canonsoftware\out.txt")
                                      
                    $i = $i+7
                    $snmp.Close()
                                  
                    Start-Sleep -milliseconds 1000 # Take a breather!
                } 
                else {  
                    $TBMonitoringPing.selectioncolor = "red"
                    $TBMonitoringPing.AppendText("$Printer not pinging")
                    $TBMonitoringPing.AppendText("`n")
                    Start-Sleep -milliseconds 1000 # Take a breather!                                   
                } 
            }         
            $LblFileSelectPing.Text = "C:\_canonsoftware\out.txt"
        } until($infinity)
    }
}
```

Comment: please read the TOUR page for this site. your posted code will not run since parts of it are undefined and therefor incomplete.

Comment: I might be misreading the code but it looks like you're doing a do-until infinity where you check the $result if the status is Success, but you never update or change the value of $result, so it will always go into the else{} section.

Comment: How would you like it to stop? You just go on until $infinity, which is not going to happen. Please add a stopping condition.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers...

1 - part of my object are indeed not declared in the code because they are in my other PS1 file....
2 - I do a do until infinity because i don't want to stop the code before i decide it...

3 - I didn't explain my problem correctly ( excuse my poor english ) ... i would like to be able to go out of the loop do until at the moment i click on a stop button ... but apprently the windows doens't respond while in the loop ... i have to stop the script with powershell ...  which is annoying because i'd like to make an executable with it ... and not have to go out of my program ...

thank you for your ideas